# javascript ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, settimeout

First I call the function reloadImage1 when the image was loaded as follow:

```
<img src="loading.gif" onload="reloadImage1(this,'newphoto.jpg')">
```

and this is reloadImage1:

```
function reloadImage1(img,isrc)
{
    setTimeout("reloadImage2(img,isrc)",2000);
}
```

and this is reloadImage2:

```
function reloadImage2(img,isrc)
{
    img.removeAttribute("onload");
    img.src = isrc;
}
```

I got the following error message when executing reloadImage1:

`ReferenceError: img is not defined`

Comment: You should never pass functions as strings to `setTimeout`, use a blank `function() {}` wrap instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `reloadImage1` to:

```
function reloadImage1(img, isrc) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        reloadImage2(img, isrc);
    }, 2000);
}
```

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/MrATK/

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
> function reloadImage1(img,isrc) {
```

*img* and *src* are local variables to the function.

```
>     setTimeout("reloadImage2(img,isrc)",2000);
> }
```

When passing a string to setTimeout, it is executed in a global context, it does not have access to the variables *img* and *src* in the function. Instead pass a function that has a closure to the original function context, e.g.:

```
  setTimeout(function() {reloadImage2(img,isrc);}, 2000);
```